# get data from javascript string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, struct

I have a string of the following structure:

```
positions = '15,-2,-3,15'
```

Which describes points, in this case `A(15, -2), B(-3, 15)`.

**Q** How would you extract the data from a string like this?

It would be better to get the result as an array of somekind of struct (e.g., `point[i].x, point[i].y`), but a multidimensional array is also suitable (e.g. `point[i][0], point[i][1]`).

Comment: Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to put it in an array - `positions.split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work, you split the string into tokens using the commas as deliminators, and then loop through that array creating some Point object with x and y.

```
var data = positions.split(','); 
var points = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    var x = data[i];
    var y = data[++i];
    points.push(new Point(x,y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use split, it will turn the values into strings, so you would need to use parseInt() or parseFloat() to convert them back to numbers.

If you just want to get to the numbers quickly without converting them into an object, you can use the power of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var positions = '15,-2,-3,15';
var arrPositions = JSON.parse("[" + positions + "]");
A([arrPositions[0], arrPositions[1]); 
B(arrPositions[2], arrPositions[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do:

```
positions = '15,-2,-3,15';

Arr = [];
pos = positions.split(',');
i = 0;
while( pos.length ){
    Arr[i++] = pos.splice( 0, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks:

```
(function f (e, s, p, r) {
     r = e.exec(s);
     return r ? [p(r[1], r[2])].concat(f(e, s, p)) : [];
 }(/(-?\d+),(-?\d+)/g, '15,-2,-3,15',
   function (x, y) { return { x: x, y: y }; }));
```